# Let P and Q are two points on curve $y=\log_{1/2}(x-\frac 12) + \log_2(\sqrt{4x^2 -4x +1})$ and P is also on $x^2+y^2=10$..

Tags: vectors

> Let P and Q are two points on curve $y=\log_{1/2}(x-\frac 12) + \log_2(\sqrt{4x^2 -4x +1})$ and P is also on $x^2+y^2=10$. Q lies in the given circle such that abscissa is an integer. Find the smallest possible value of $\vec {OP}.\vec{OQ}$

After some simplification of the first expression I found $y=1$. So P is $(3,1)$

Now it is possible to have $\vec {OQ}$ perpendicular to $\vec {OP}$, so minimum value should be zero but the ans is 4.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should fix the title.

Comment: @jjagmath done, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Something is odd with the problem. If $P$ and $Q$ are on both the curve and the circle, since the curve only intersects the circle at one point, we have $P=Q$.